# Custom Picker View for iOS 6.1

Tags: uipickerview

I am trying to setup a simple custom picker view that has two components based on arrays.  The first array (used in component 0) is defined as:

```
onesScore = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[onesScore addObject:@"5"];
[onesScore addObject:@"6"];
[onesScore addObject:@"7"];
[onesScore addObject:@"8"];
[onesScore addObject:@"9"];
```

The second array (used in component 1) is defined as:

```
tenthsScore = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[tenthsScore addObject:@"0"];
[tenthsScore addObject:@"1"];
[tenthsScore addObject:@"2"];
[tenthsScore addObject:@"3"];
[tenthsScore addObject:@"4"];
[tenthsScore addObject:@"5"];
[tenthsScore addObject:@"6"];
[tenthsScore addObject:@"7"];
[tenthsScore addObject:@"8"];
[tenthsScore addObject:@"9"];
```

The I am using the following code to create the custom view:

```
 - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)picker viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
UILabel* retval = (id)view;
if (!retval){
    retval= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [picker rowSizeForComponent:component].width, [picker rowSizeForComponent:component].height)];

    if (component == 0)
    {
        retval.text = [onesScore objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else if (component == 1)
    {
        retval.text = [tenthsScore objectAtIndex:row];
    }

retval.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:48];
retval.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
retval.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
}
return retval;

}
```

The UI of the picker works great and first component loads correctly, the issue is that for the second component I get:

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3

It's not loading the full "tenthsScore" array properly.  I'm at a complete loss.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, please make an effort to format your code properly.  Doing so makes it easier  for us to help you.

Anyway, you're only setting the label's `text` when you're first creating the label.  In the case when you're reusing a label, you just return the reused label unchanged.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)picker viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    UILabel* retval = (id)view;
    if (!retval){
        retval= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [picker rowSizeForComponent:component].width, [picker rowSizeForComponent:component].height)];
        retval.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:48];
        retval.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
        retval.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }

    if (component == 0) {
        retval.text = [onesScore objectAtIndex:row];
    } else if (component == 1) {
        retval.text = [tenthsScore objectAtIndex:row];
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rob...simple fix that I missed!  Sorry about the formatting issue.  I appreciate the help!